# {C#}{SQL} Selecting from table and getting only 1 column

Tags: c#, sql, select, format

I am selecting from mysql table. Here is my code :

```
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM `" + BanditPlugin.Instance.Configuration.Instance.SQLArrestTable + "` where date=(select max(date) from `"+ BanditPlugin.Instance.Configuration.Instance.SQLArrestTable + "` where date<sysdate());";
            connection.Open();
            object result = command.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            return result.ToString();
```

I am getting only 1 column named player from there.
I want to get it like :

> player | caller | date

How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: how does your table looks?

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas http://i.imgur.com/RlqzjPS.png

Comment: Did you try specifying columns like "SELECT player, caller, date FROM..."? Have you tried executing generated query directly in database?

Comment: Command looks fine, table looks fine; must be how the command is executed and/or the method used to populate your objects. Unfortunately you failed to provide those blocks of code.

Comment: @MadMyche Updated.

Comment: You are using `ExecuteScalar`. This method returns only one salar value - the first value of the first column.  
You should either use a `DataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable` or use `ExecuteReader` and iterate the results in a while loop.